# This Unity Scene is not loading

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't know why my scene is not loading, can I get help?
When I press the button nothing happens.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class gamecontroller : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text points;
    public void Start() {
        points.text = Score.scoreval + " POINTS";
    }
    
    public void Restart() {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("SampleScene");
        Score.scoreval = 0;
    }
    public void Menu() 
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
        Score.scoreval = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to add the scene to your build settings. See [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html).

Comment: When you press the key, does a red error warning appear in the Console?

Comment: Could you show your build settings and the Inspector setup of according button(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason might be that you did not assign the scene in your build. This is an easy fix if this is the case. To check if it is, you can go to the `Build Settings...` under the `File` tab. Once in there, you should see the `Scenes In Build` category, in there you should also see your scene(s). If not, you will need to assign them by going to each scene and pressing `Add Open Scenes`. Once done, it should work properly from there.

Not sure if this is an issue, it has been a while since I have coded in C#. But, in my scene manager, I wrote the scenes name as such:

```
    public void StartButton()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(labScene);
}
```

Not sure if that matters, but I thought I might as well put that out there.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug from Unity side as it has happened with me sometimes that whenever I'm trying to load the scene using the LoadScene method by passing the SceneName as the parameter, Unity throws up an error even when those scenes have been added in the Build Settings.

Removing the scenes from the build settings and adding them again is what worked for me. :)